# Expo bare workflow google signin auth error

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, google-signin

Google SignIn was working fine in managed workflow but stopped working when ejected. react-native-unimodules is properly configured. All other configurations are exactly the same. Getting following error.

Authorization Error

Error 400: Invalid_request
invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing authority: null:/oauth2redirect/google[image]

ClientId is checked multiple times for confirmation.

**Update:** I ended up using the "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin" package and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `redirect_uri` (`null:/oauth2redirect/google`) isn't good,

your need to follow those instructions:

- **Bundle ID**: Must match the value of `ios.bundleIdentifier` in your app.json.
- Your app needs to conform to the URI scheme matching your bundle identifier.

  - Bare workflow: Run `npx uri-scheme add <your bundle id> --ios`
- To test this you can:

  1. Eject to bare: `expo eject` and run `yarn ios`
  2. Create a custom client: `expo client:ios`
  3. Build a production IPA: `expo build:ios`
- Whenever you change the values in app.json you'll need to rebuild the native app.

[source](https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#ios-native)

Comment: Thanks. But this does not effect anything. URI Scheme was missing. But after adding it i re ran the project but no use. I am testing on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You should check some point below:

1.iosclientId is correct?

[image]

2.AccessToken should as this

const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, accessToken);
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)

//Note the first parameter null

3.Add ClientID in Sign-in Method Firebase->Google->Enable->Safelist Client IDs.... -> paste ClientID into input-> Press 'Add'-> Done run yourProject

Comment: (1) checked and confirmed, (2) didn't even reached at this point. (3) added it but no use.

Comment: Please post code GoogleSignIn here you can not capture each error like this

Comment: okay i will update my question. I am giving you bounty as you atleast replied to my comment.

Comment: If you still have the error go ahead and add code to your questionnaire so people can continue to help you